# Div Hide And Show

Tags: javascript, html

In the picture, all the prices are in EUR, the prices of tr are hidden on the site.
When I click on the link above, TL and TL prices will be shown and euro prices will be hidden.
When I click on the euro link, the tl will be hidden and the euro will be displayed.
There is a problem in the code but I couldn't solve it
thanks in advance

```
<button onclick="TL()">TL</button>-<button onclick="EURO()">EURO</button>

<div id="fiyat"> 29.5 </div><div id="fiyattl" style="display: none;" > 400 TL </div>
<div id="fiyat1"> 29.5 </div><div id="fiyattl1" style="display: none;" > 500TL</div>
<div id="fiyat2"> 29.5 </div><div id="fiyattl2" style="display: none;" > 600TL </div>
<div id="fiyat3"> 29.5 </div><div id="fiyattl3" style="display: none;" > 700 TL</div>
<div id="fiyat4"> 29.5 </div><div id="fiyattl4" style="display: none;" > 800 TL</div>

<script>
 function TL() {
   var x = document.getElementById("fiyattl");
   var y = document.getElementById("fiyattl1");
   var z= document.getElementById("fiyattl2");
   var t = document.getElementById("fiyattl3");
   var w = document.getElementById("fiyattl4");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    }
   if (y.style.display === "none") {
    y.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (z.style.display === "none") {
    z.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    z.style.display = "none";
    }
     if (t.style.display === "none") {
    t.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    t.style.display = "none";
     }
    if (w.style.display === "none") {
     w.style.display = "block";
     } else {
     w.style.display = "none";
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem - does the toggle not work?

Comment: Typo - all of your inline styles don't have closing quotes (`"`) - on [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6Lg2qj8/) with this it works

Comment: Well by just looking at it I can see you did not close a " " correctly.
Look at your first tag with ID: fiyat  .. if you keep reading the line and go to style="display: none;  , you will notice that you did not close  " " your quotes. and you did that on all 5 of them 
on another note. it will be easier to debug your code if you use meaningful variable names.  X Y Z will get confusing when and if the code expands

Comment: another thing I forgot to mention. if you are going to hide/ unhide all. you could do it a lot easier with just one  ID called fiyattl and assign it to all 5 of your prices.  cause in that case you could dynamically add extra Items from a database let's say. and it will automatically hide/ unhide without you needing anything extra.

Comment: @Demeteor - it would be better to use a class, ID should always be unique

Comment: @CanO'Spam yes exactly!

Comment: Can you write an example based on the codes I wrote or using a class?

Comment: @30SecondTv - see answer from Professor Abronsius

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a className to these `div` elements that reflects the currency then you can identify all the nodes that are to be either hidden or displayed quite easily using native javascript methods. In the following the inline event handlers are replaced with externally registered listeners that use the `name` of the clicked  button to identify the price nodes that have that name as the class attribute. You could use `dataset` attributes instead of course but there is no need to use multiple IDs which can easily become hard to maintain and prone to troubles.

```js
/*
  querySelectorAll will attempt to match DOM elements based upon the
  expression used. Here we find both/all buttons in the DOM - this
  could be honed to identify ONLY the buttons of interest if required
  by modifying the buttons (add a className for instance) and editing the
  expression used.
  
  The button collection is iterated through and an event listener is
  added to process the `click` event.
*/

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  /*
    The click event handler
    Identify the DIV elements that have the class attribute that matches the name of the button.
    Iterate through that collection and set the display property to "block"
  */
  let col=document.querySelectorAll( 'div.'+this.getAttribute('name') );
      col.forEach( n => n.style.display='block' )
   /*
    then identify the DIV elements that are not relevant, iterate through
    that collection and assign them as hidden.
   */
      col=document.querySelectorAll('div:not([class="'+this.getAttribute('name')+'"])');
      col.forEach( n => n.style.display='none' );
}));
```

```html
<button name='tl'>TL</button>-<button name='euro'>EURO</button>

<div class='euro'>29.5</div><div class='tl' style='display:none;'>400 TL</div>
<div class='euro'>29.5</div><div class='tl' style='display:none;'>500TL</div>
<div class='euro'>29.5</div><div class='tl' style='display:none;'>600TL</div>
<div class='euro'>29.5</div><div class='tl' style='display:none;'>700 TL</div>
<div class='euro'>29.5</div><div class='tl' style='display:none;'>800 TL</div>
```

Comment: Is it really okay to change someone's code so much from the original?  I mean the code you posted is nowhere near what he posted. don't get me wrong what you posted is amazing. but it makes me wonder if it really helps the dude who asked in the long run.  I might be misunderstanding the purpose of SO

Comment: I think it is OK but I understand your point. To my mind there was a lot in the original HTML that is superfluous - is it not the aim to make the markup as clean as possible? As for the javascript function that clearly cannot be scaled easily like that so I showed an alternative approach

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - I'd argue that while this is (IMO) the best answer to the question at hand, perhaps some code explanation might help the OP also as they appear to be quite green in JS?

Comment: A fair point @CanO'Spam

Comment: Yes, I like how much cleaner you made it. was just wondering about the javascript part. cause judging from the original post. I think the user might not understand the solution and just copy-paste it. and again I agree with your code. and your logic. because now even if you add 1000+  price lines. there would not be a need to change the javascript.
it's just me trying to understand if it's okay to help in that way, cause most of the time I try to guide them in the right direction cause I thought that's how we are supposed to do it.  but it seems I was wrong ^^

Comment: Thank you for the information you provided. but there is a problem. When I add the codes to the site (I am deleting the asp codes), the codes are working in the normal html file. The site I have made is asp and when I want to switch from euro prices to TL prices while working here, it shows and returns to euro prices. Is there anything else I should do? (There is an asp loop on the site and it will change approximately 50 div tags)

Comment: I figured out where the problem is. Since I wrote the codes you wrote inside the form tag, there was a problem in displaying them on the site. It worked when I took the button code out of the form. thank you so much.